# How to stop Visual Studio 2012 from closing console window after execution?

Tags: visual-studio-2012

How to stop Visual Studio 2012 from closing console window after execution without using `system("pause");` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Right click your Project -> Properties -> Configuration Properties -> Linker -> System.

Then select `Console (/SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE)` in “SubSystem” option.

Comment: Finally figured out this works when you run the app by pressing Ctrl+F5, instead of just F5.

Comment: This is what was needed. Every other thread is saying Ctrl+F5 but it doesn't work unless this option is selected.

Comment: I don't see that option when going in the projet properties.

Answer (score 0):

Just click on the far left of the VS code window to place a break-point (usually opposite of "Return 0;" or later).